# Replacing Values after Dataframe subset

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am trying to do **target encoding** on the column 'X0' where I want to replace every unique values (levels) in X0 with the **target's median** but in a **cross-validated manner**. The problem is the last line

> train.loc[test_index,:].loc[boolean,"X0"] = int(j[1].y.median())

where I subset the test fold and then again subset to that group to replace the median it doesnt seem to work. Any help on replacing this median into that dataframe would be highly appreciated.

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
kf = KFold(train.shape[0], n_folds=NFOLDS, shuffle=True, random_state=SEED)
kf


for i ,(train_index,test_index) in enumerate(kf):
    train_dataset = train.iloc[train_index,:]
    for j in train_dataset.groupby('X0'):
        boolean = train.iloc[test_index].X0 == j[0]
        print train.loc[test_index,:].loc[boolean,"X0"] 
        print int(j[1].y.median())
        train.loc[test_index,:].loc[boolean,"X0"] = int(j[1].y.median())
```

I could still see the categorical levels only inside and not the numerical values.

Comment: It's difficult to help without an example.